# mysql like not wildcard

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table:

```
+---------+----------+
+  Items  +  Person  +
+---------+----------+
+ 2,99,75 +  Jack    +
+ 4,9,63  +  Rose    +
+---------+----------+
```

Now I do a simple

`LIKE :items`

and binding it using

`$stmt->bindParam(':items',$item,PDO::PARAM_STR);`

where

`$item = "%9%"`.

The result contains both **Jack** and **Rose**, which is wrong because I expected to have **Rose** only as my result. It seems that `LIKE` sees both 99 and 9. How can I restrict my `LIKE` to have only 9 because that was the value of `$items`?

Comment: While I understand you probably can't change the schema of the database, this is fundamentally the wrong way to represent this sort of data.

Comment: Its because % represent one or more character (anything). So 99 will match the "%9%"

Comment: @Interrobang, what do you mean?

Comment: Databases are awesome at allowing you to map relationships between data. To do their job well, they make use of certain structures-- namely, the idea of rows and columns. Each column should contain only one data element, in the form most appropriate for the element. (There are exceptions like JSON in Postgres, but semantics) So you should really be representing the relationship between these users and their IDs in a one-to-many way, where one user might have multiple rows of data, each with a single integer id. Then finding people who own Item 9 is as easy as "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Item = 9"

Comment: @Class `LIKE '%,9,%'` will fail on `8,9` or on `9,8` or any other example where the 9 is at the start or end

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good to do.  However, I pose this alternative based on the fact that Items appears to be ID's.

If you need to query off comma separated values I would recommend a separate table.  Using LIKE to query in a single field will never truly be fool-proof and could be a security concern.  Try this.

Table 1: Person

```
+---------+----------+
+  ID     +  Person  +
+---------+----------+
+ <int>   + <string> +
+---------+----------+
```

Table 2: Item

```
+---------+----------+
+ PersonID+  ItemID  +
+---------+----------+
+ <int>   + <int>    +
+---------+----------+
```

Then use joins to query both tables as needed.

```
SELECT * FROM Person INNER JOIN Items ON Items.PersonID = Person.ID 
   WHERE Items.ItemID = '9';
```

This should provide you with every record in `Person` that has `ItemID` "9" associated with them.

Perhaps this might help: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 1):

Its because % represent one or more character (anything). So 99 will match the "%9%"

If you want only 9, you can try with

```
"%,9,%"
```

Comment: This will not work for all cases, e.g. "9,1,2" or "43,56,9".  You would have to add `OR LEFT(Items, 2) = '9,' OR RIGHT(Items, 2) = ',9'`.  However, this is NOT a solution to the problem.  It's just digging him deeper in bad code.  Downvote for answering the question incorrectly and for not helping the OP build a proper DB.

Comment: Indeed, the user should work again on the DB design (and use relation between tables) but it is not the direct question. I'm not digging him anything, just explain the behaviour of the `%`. Downvote what you want dude. don't care.

Comment: Your answer still didn't solve the OP's problem.  You missed 2 cases that I identified above.  Good job teaching him how LIKE works without solving the problem or teaching him anything useful about database design.  That's not what SO is about.

Comment: There is no mention about `9,%` or `%,9` in the question, and my example is just here to explain how LIKE work. you have voted down, so please, stop boring me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the main issue on this is what @interrobang said, the way you are representing the data.

If this table X that you show is the list itens for each person, you should have a column with the person id and another column with the item id, and multiple lines to represent multiple itens for each person. Doing like this your search would be much faster and easier to use and mantain in the future.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90ee4/1)

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE item (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE person_item (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     person_id int,
     item_id int
);

ALTER TABLE person_item ADD UNIQUE (person_id,item_id);

INSERT INTO person(id,name) VALUES
(1, 'John'),
(2, 'Mary'),
(3, 'Oliver');


INSERT INTO item (id,name) VALUES
(1,'Pen'),
(2,'Pencil'),
(3,'Book');

INSERT INTO person_item (person_id,item_id) VALUES
(1,1),
(1,3),
(2,2),
(3,1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select p.name from person_item pi, person p, item i
where pi.person_id = p.id
and pi.item_id = i.id
and i.name LIKE 'Book%'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90ee4/1/0)**:

```
| NAME |
--------
| John |
```

Comment: oh well ... :) this will work. without referential integrity but will work hehehehe

Comment: take a look on : INSERT INTO person_item (person_id,item_id) VALUES
(1,1),
(1,3), ... one person with multiple itens ... ;)

Comment: 100% agree, add : ALTER TABLE person_item ADD UNIQUE (person_id,item_id);